# Laravel 5 form model binding with hasMany

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have two models: `Category` and `CategoryValue`.

Inside my `Category` model I have:

```
public function values()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CategoryValue');
}
```

Inside my `CategoryValue` I have:

```
function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

In my edit view, I have my form model binding like so:

```
{!! Form::model($category, ['route' => ['category.update', $category->slug], 'method' => 'PATCH']) !!}
    @include('partials.categoryForm')
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Where `$category` is a chosen `Category` Model.

The categoryForm partial looks like:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Name') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    {!! $errors->first('name', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('slug') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    {!! Form::label('slug', 'Slug') !!}
    {!! Form::text('slug', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    {!! $errors->first('slug', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Save Page', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
</div>
```

That's all working, but when editing the Category, I'd like to be able to edit (add/remove) associate `CategoryValue`s. To start, I want the items returned from `$category->values` to be inside a `textarea` with each `CategoryValue` on a new line.

I can think of a couple of ways to do this: use a `@foreach` and generate the `textarea`, or popular a variable and use that in the binding. I'm not sure which of these, if either, is the "Laravel" way to do it. I'm also not sure if either of those can be used to update the records in the DB properly. How should this be done?